# looping functions to create a new dataframe and then within each dataframe loop another action

Tags: r, loops, dplyr

Currently I have a huge database (replacing my database with `mtcars` for examples) which I'm using:

```
cyc_6 <- filter( cars, str_detect(cyc, '6'))
```

to create a new dataframe that only contains rows which have 6 stored in cyc. The reason why I need to do it like this is because some times its 6.3, 6.2 etc.

From there I'm using :

```
cyc_6 %>%
+     group_by(cyc) %>%
+     summarise(Total = mean(qsec, na.rm = TRUE)) %>%
+     arrange(desc(Total))
```

to find the average 1/4 mile per number of cylinders (cyclinders in this case aren't whole numbers, hence the need to group function)

What I want to know is how can I automate any of this through looping.

I know that I need to make a vector containing all my new variables c(cyc_6), but then I'm not sure what my function would be.

Any help would be very appreciated.

Comment: You probably want to use `cut` but you have not really described what grouping rules to use, so maybe you want `floor`. Hard to tell.